# Issues with an infinitely running while-loop

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I have a program that downloads a set of random files periodically and checks their sizes, then chooses one with a size above a given threshold (currently 6KB).
The check is working fine but if the set of files contains none that satisfy the threshold check it keeps searching through the set, forever.

Here is my code (the function `chosen()` is returns a `random.choice` on the directory with the files, the variable `z_file` is the file selected with the `chosen()` func, and `size` is a function that returns a `get.size` value for the randomly chosen file) -

```
threshold = 6000
while True:  
    z_file = chosen()
    file_size = size(z_file)
    if file_size < threshold:
        print(z_file + " is too small")
    else:
        break
print(z_file , "is at least 6KB -" , file_size , "bytes ...")
```

Normally it works fine but occasionally there is no file  greater than 6KB, and the result loops forever -

```
PAGE 1 contains [1] images
PAGE 2 contains [1] images
PAGE 3 contains [3] images

pic3_3.png is too small
pic2_1.png is too small
pic3_3.png is too small
pic3_1.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic1_1.png is too small
pic3_1.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic3_1.png is too small
pic3_1.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic3_1.png is too small
pic2_1.png is too small
pic3_3.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic2_1.png is too small
pic3_2.png is too small
pic3_3.png is too small
pic3_3.png is too small
pic3_3.png is too small
```

I'm sure my while loop is poorly written and I'm using the break clause incorrectly but I cannot get my head around it. Any assistance/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
threshold = 6000
n = 0
TOTAL_FILES_NUMBER = 3
checked_files = defaultdict(int)
while True:  
    z_file = chosen()
    file_size = size(z_file)
    if checked_files[z_file] == 0:
        n += 1
        checked_files[z_file] = 1
    if file_size < threshold:
        print(z_file + " is too small")
    else:
        break
    if n == TOTAL_FILES_NUMBER:
        break
print(z_file , "is at least 6KB -" , file_size , "bytes ...")
```

One way to overcome this problem is to know the total number of files in your directory (in the above code I assumed it is a total of 3 files) now the problem is that you choose a random file each time and you don't know if you choose it before or not so you can't simply make an integer `n` and increment it each iteration and when it reaches the total number you simply break, because then you can check the same file 3 times and it will break from the loop as it had checked all the 3 files.

So, to solve this problem we created a `dictionary` called `checked_files` it will keep track of each file and whether we choose it already or not depending on the value of the file key if it is 0 then we didn't choose that file already and if it is 1 then we had already checked this file before.

And depending on this we can check using the above code if we checked all of the files in our directory or not.

Comment: This is interesting although I thought ```defaultdict``` was used for inserting a key where one does not yet exist, which I don't think solves my issue... Also, in this case the the while loop now no longer ensures ```threshold``` is met and will now allow files smaller than 6000bytes...
I do like the counter idea though, I can't believe I hadn't thought of that, I'm still learning python so I need to look into implementing properly.

Comment: `defaultdict` is used to ensure the datatype of the `values` in the dictionary not the datatype of `keys` which can be of any type, but I can't figure out how the while loop allow for smaller values because I didn't change your if statement in my example?

Comment: I encountered the threshold not being checked properly at one point but I may have rewritten the breaks in the wrong order in the if / else pieces. To save time I just pasted your solution in (did you edit it?) and now it's not accepting <6000byte files anymore, but it's also not resolving the issue, the while loop still executes the checks infinitely. I'm not understanding what part limits the size-check iterations.

Comment: did you change the `TOTAL_FILES_NUMBER` ?

Comment: Yes, I initially set it much higher (as my set can contain hundreds of files) but this didn't do anything to catch my infinite loop issue originally posted. I thought I'd try it on a limited set which only has 2 files, both of which are too small (this causes the issue..), so I set TOTAL_FILES_NUMBER to 1 - and the output is :
```pic2_1.png is too small
pic2_1.png is at least 6KB - 67 bytes```

So if the number is higher the infinite loop still occurs, if it's lower the threshold-check is ignored and files <6KB are accepted..

Comment: if you have 2 files you should set it to `2` not `1`, and my solution assumes that you know already the total number of files that you have, if you can't determine the total number of files then you should go with @RandomGuy answer.

Comment: The number of files can vary but can be held in a var so would still be able to use this, however even set to the exact number of the files in the set, I get the same result, the threshold check is ignored and files <6KB are accepted - 
```pic2_1.png is at least 6KB - 67 bytes ```
I'm going to look into the shuffle method instead, but appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to access all the files random.choice is bad idea I would suggest random.shuffle

```py
threshold = 6000
for i in random.shuffle(file_list):  
    file_size = size(i)
    if file_size < threshold:
        print(i + " is too small")
    else:
        print(i , "is at least 6KB -" , file_size , "bytes ...")
        break
    print("no file above threshold")
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why random.choice is a bad idea, and what random.shuffle does instead?

Comment: random shuffle just shuffles a list u give as a param its the same thing as randomly picking from a list but now we can use a for loop to not go forever(also for loops have shown better performance to while loops)

Comment: I wish I could easily implement this but I'm using functions for the original ```random.choice``` and subsequent ```get.size```, and being a noob I am unable to get ```random.shuffle``` working in any way with my current set-up. I have decided to cap size-checks with a static number (say 300, anything's better than infinite..), I'm still having issues with that but that's a whole different post.. Thanks anyway